# Performance penalties from sqlite views

Tags: sqlite, view, database-performance

I have a select query, as the following:

```
select distinct
  ...some fields

from
  table_a,
  table_b,
  table_c,
  ...more tables

where
  table_a.id = table_b.id and
  ... (rest of the tables) and
  some_field_that_i_care_about = 42

order by
  my_field
```

If I run that query as-is, it takes around half a second to get me the results that I expect.

Nevertheless, if I convert that same query to a view (excluding the `some_field_that_i_care_about = 42` condition) and then I run:

```
select *
from the_view
where some_field_that_i_care_about = 42
```

the query takes around 40 seconds to return the same data.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Show the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output for both queries.

Answer (score 4):

Views are just syntactic sugar for subqueries. Such subqueries usually do not result in a performance penalty because they can be [flattened](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening), i.e., merged into the outer query.

However, in this case, the ORDER BY prevents the flattening.

Just drop the ORDER BY from the view; the ordering of the subquery is [ignored by the outer query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) anyway. (If you want the result to be sorted, you must use ORDER BY in the outermost query.)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the query still takes around 40 seconds. Any other ideas?